# How to clear messages in Bot Builder SDK for .NET

Tags: botframework, bots

I want to clear the previous chat messages using Bot Builder SDK for .NET. Is there any option to clear the messages C# code of Bot Dialogue.

Looking for some option to clear all the messages in the screenshot by pressing some "clear" button

[Sample ScreenShot using BOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agrPu.png)

Comment: `I want to clear the previous chat messages in Bot Builder SDK for .NET. ` Could you clarify more about your requirements?

Comment: Looking some option to clear all the messages in the above attached screenshot by pressing some "clear" button

Comment: which channel you are using now?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs & AdaptiveCards which are available in C#.

Comment: [Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) means webchat, directline, facebook etc. which channel you are using now?

Comment: webchat in asp.net azurewebsites.

Comment: You could try to send event activity that indicates clearing messages command to your webchat user, and then webchat client listens for a specific event from the bot and clear previous messages (wc-message).[The Backchannel mechanism](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#the-backchannel) would be helpful to achieve the requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your useful suggestion in webchat. My requirement is to clear the messages in the Self Service ChatBot using C# code, probably this async method where we are serving some SQL reports by ChatBot (public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity). Reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Comment: Are you trying to delete the messages from memory or just clear the chat window of all messages? I'm not sure what you mean by "using C# code" in this instance, as it sounds like a frontend problem.

Comment: `My requirement is to clear the messages in the Self Service ChatBot using C# code, probably this async method where we are serving some SQL reports by ChatBot` Do you store message history in SQL DB and you want to delete all message records? Or clear the all messages within chat window of specific channel?

Comment: If you'd like to clear the frontend message log, it would be best to implement a custom version of the [webchat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#customizing-webchat)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to clear the previous chat messages using Bot Builder SDK for .NET. Is there any option to clear the messages C# code of Bot Dialogue.

You configured your bot to connect to the Web Chat channel, the message could be sent from bot to your website app that embedded web chat control. As I and @MarkB mentioned in comments, to clear the messages rendered in your webchat window within your website, you could [build and use your customized Web Chat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#building-web-chat). I built a customized Web chat and implemented clearing messages functionality, you can refer to it.

1) add clear button and implement clearing message function for button click event in `Chat.tsx`

```
{
    !!state.format.chatTitle &&
        <div className="wc-header">
            <span>{ typeof state.format.chatTitle === 'string' ? state.format.chatTitle : state.format.strings.title }</span>
        </div>

}
{
    <button className="wc-clear" onClick={ () => this.onClickClear() }>
        <span>Clear Messages</span>
    </button>
}
```

*the implementation of `onClickClear`:*

```
/*remove messages*/

private onClickClear() {
    /*alert("111");*/
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("wc-message-wrapper"))
    .forEach(element => element.remove());
}
```

2) specify styles for clear button in `botchat.scss`

```
.wc-clear{
    background-color:#0078d7;
    box-shadow: 0 1px $c_shadow;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: $c01;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: $headerTotalHeight - $headerPaddingTop - $headerPaddingBottom;
    /*left: 0;*/
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    padding: $headerPaddingTop $headerPaddingRight $headerPaddingBottom $headerPaddingLeft;
    position: relative;
    /*right: 0;
    top: 0;*/
    display: block;
    float: right;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

3) build to our own version Web Chat and use it in website

*Test result:*

[image]

Or you can use [the Backchannel mechanism](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#the-backchannel) to send a specific **event** activity to your webchat client, and then webchat client listens for that specific event and clear previous messages by removing all  elements with `'wc-message-wrapper'` class via JavaScript.

> we are serving some SQL reports by ChatBot

If you’d like to access your SQL database in your bot application `MessagesController` or `Dialog`, you can use and leverage a familiar ORM framework. Besides, if you’d like to connect to your on-premises database from your bot application that is hosting on Azure, you can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Bot built with c# and embedded in a HTML page using Direcline bot channel.  Then the following code will help you in clearing the chat messages.

Add an Restart / Clear chat button on the chat head

```
    <i id="restart" class="fa fa-retweet headicons" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left;" title="Restart Chat"></i>
```

Adding to that, use the below onclick event,

```
$("#restart").click(function(){

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("webchat__stacked_indented_content"))
.forEach(element => element.remove());
```

});

one drawback with this approach is that, we can't get the welcome message again if we use this approach in client site. to get the welcome message again in the chat window use the similar approach in C# coding of the bot and call the onmemberadd event again to trigger the welcome message.